# How to display multiple pictures stacked on top of each other in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

On a web page, I want to show a list of albums and next to each album name i want to show a stacked list of pictures on top of each other.  What is the best way to dynamically take a list of pictures and have them stacked on top of each other

Here is an example:

[image: picture of images stack atop one another]

Comment: When you say dynamically take a list of pictures, where are they coming from. I would imagine stacking img elements within an unordered list with CSS would be quite simple, but its hard to say without a sample of your code

Comment: @mu is too short - stacked vertically like you see on most tools that show an album with a stack of the pictures in that album

Comment: @mu is too short - i put an example of what i am trying to do

Comment: So you do mean overlapping or "stacked in a pile" rather than "stacked vertically".

Comment: @mu is too short - yes, i mean stacked in a pile on top of each other

Comment: [Creating a polaroid photo viewer with CSS3 and jQuery](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/creating_a_polaroid_photo_viewer_with_css3_and_jquery.html)?

Comment: [Polaroid Gallery v.1.01](http://www.no3dfx.com/polaroid/)?

Comment: @Shef - that is using flash . . i am looking for a javascript solution

Comment: @ooo, see what i've posted. if you would like a more complete solution I can show you how to implement some more control into where the images are displayed and what rotation is applied. also what `z-index` you will want to apply. It is also very easy for you to bind events to my solution (opposed to canvas)

Comment: You might want to look into using canvas to do this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Why not just build one? it wouldn't be hard. Here is a small rotate prototype i've worked up (took maybe 5 minutes to write)

```
Element.prototype.rotate = function(d) {
    var s = "rotate(" + d + "deg)";
    if (this.style) { // regular DOM Object
        this.style.MozTransform = s;
        this.style.WebkitTransform = s;
        this.style.OTransform = s;
        this.style.transform = s;
    }
    this.setAttribute("rotation", d);
};
```

then you can use to it rotate a list of images.. [see (not very good :P) example here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/JKQee/)

[Better Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/JKQee/32/)
[Best Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ULNrC/)

---

Looks like the OP wants *more*
How is this for *close-to-the-example*? *i think a few angles may be off...*
[image: Example Output]

Or [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ULNrC/14/)

Comment: 2015 update: don't extend the Element.prototype, write a utility method and pass the element.

Answer (score 6):

To rotate the images you either need the new CSS3 features or a canvas element, new to HTML5.

Writing some JS functions to aid you in the rotating process it's a matter of minutes.

I would say the best library is the one you write.

Anyway, if I had to choose one I would choose [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: From the website "Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+."

Comment: Check the examples on the website, in particular [this](http://raphaeljs.com/image-rotation.html) for the image rotation. Really fluid across all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Libraries will just help you out with manipulating the dom and responding to events. The answer lies in the way you see the problem, how you will represent the data, how you will handle the dynamic data that comes to you.

Images are html elements, so they can be manipulated with CSS3 like Jose Faeti said. Now for the *dynamic part* I would suggest you take a look at backbone.js (http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/).

In a few words, backbone.js will help you defined albums and pictures as standalone entities, hook views to those data models - views that will automatically adapt when new data comes via ajax from the server - and to top it all of, it uses jQuery for dom selection, so:

1) You get a nice OOP-ish approach to defining your images data
2) You get a nice Model-View View-Model relationship that updates itself easily
3) You get jQuery as a dom selection and manipulation tool